# Content in popover is not updating even after changing the content value in angular js popover

Tags: angularjs, popover

`noteContent` function is called on `ng-mouseenter` and
`content`, `$element` attributes are passed to it. When we again call this function with different content then popover content is not updated.

```
$scope.noteContent = function (content, element) {
    var __popOverNoteHTML = `<div class="as-vc" >${content}</div>`
    var currentElement = $(element.target);
    var noteHover = $(currentElement).parents("#note-hover");
    
    $(noteHover).popover({
        content: __popOverNoteHTML,
        animation: true,
        placement: "left",
        html: "true",
        container: "body",
        trigger: "hover"       
    }); 
}
```

Comment: `popeverHTML` is not populated anywhere and `__popOverNoteHTML` is not used anywhere. If its not working even then, can you try compiling the content(`$compile(popoverHTML)(scope)`) or run `$digest` manually?

Comment: sorry it is __popOverNoteHTML not popever using __popOverNoteHTML is also not updating popover content